# Поиск по многомерному массиву PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть массив такой структуры:

```
Array(
    'category1'=>Array(
        0=>"some long string";
        1=>"another long string";
        'text'=>"one more str";
    ),
    'category2'=>Array(
        0=>"test1";
        'text'=>"test3";
    ),
    ...
);
```

Мне нужно, чтобы по значению, например, "test1" я находил категорию элемента, в данном случае - `category2`. Как это можно реализовать максимально производительно (такой поиск используется у меня в скрипте довольно часто) ?

**UPD:** Код моей реализации:

```
function search($needle, $haystack){
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$item){
        if(in_array($needle, $item))
            return $key;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Он, конечно, работает, но хотелось бы найти какое-нибудь сверхбыстрое решение.

Comment: А где код вашей реализации поиска?

Comment: @Visman Добавил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если структуру не менять и предполагать универсальное решение, то полный перебор в худшем случае - единственный путь. Какой-то существенный бонус может дать явное или неявное изменение самой структуры.

Если искать надо по одному массиву и часто, то можно затратить больше памяти, некоторое время на обработку первого вызова, но получить очень существенный бонус по скорости для последующих вызовов до уровня `O(1)` - реализовать `hashmap`. В PHP, где ассоциативный массив уже hash, достаточно создать вспомогательный массив вида `item => category`

```
$search = function($needle) use($rg) {
    static $hashmap = null;
    if (! $hashmap) {
        // первый запуск, заполняем индекс
        foreach ($rg as $cat => $elements) {
            foreach ($elements as $item) {
                $hashmap[ $item ] = $cat;
            }
        }
    }

    return isset($hashmap[ $needle ])
        ? $hashmap[ $needle ]
        : null;
};
```

Я намеренно воспользовался реализацией через замыкание чтобы показать привязку работы метода к определённому массиву.

Напомню про проблему с необходимостью инвалидации сохранённого в функции списка значений при изменении исходного массива.

Существует ошибка, если идентичные строки могут быть в нескольких разных категориях. Ваша реализация этой ошибке так же подвержена, поэтому ничего с этим делать я не стал.

Comment: Извините, а что значит в вашем коде `use`? И как тогда отслеживать изменения исходного массива, чтобы `hash` оставался актуальным, можно ли присвоить `$hashmap` `null` извне, чтобы обновить его?

Comment: `use` - часть синтаксиса замыкания. Позволяет использовать переменную $rg, существующую во время создания функции. Сбросить $hashmap можно или добавлением нового параметра специально для этого или пересозданием функции. Как отслеживать изменения исходного массива - уже полностью ваша задача. Я не знаю, может это readonly конфиг и никаких действий и не нужно. Для изменяемого массива - можно всю структуру, включая сам исходный массив инкапсулировать в объект и общаться через публичный интерфейс этого объекта, не используя напрямую этот массив из остального кода.